# EF extension method: "This function can only be invoked from LINQ to Entities."

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, lambda

I have made an extension method to EF entities:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> WildcardSearch<T>(this IEnumerable<T> entity, 
                                                 string param, Func<T, 
                                                 string> selector)
{
    return entity.Where(l => SqlFunctions.PatIndex(param, selector(l)) > 0);
}

//exception: This function can only be invoked from LINQ to Entities.
result = context.FOO.WildcardSearch(id, x => x.Id).ToList();
```

I get the exception above if I try to use it.

However, if I run (what I assume) the very same code directly on my collection, it works as intented.

Why do I get the exception, and is there any way to fix this?

Similar threads suggest changing the type to `IQueryable`, but it doesn't seem to help.

```
//this works
result = context.FOO.Where(x => 
              SqlFunctions.PatIndex(id, x.Id) > 0).ToList();
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It needs to be `IQueryable<T>` and `Expression<Func<...>>`; unfortunately this means rebuilding the expression tree - for example:

```
public static IQueryable<T> WildcardSearch<T>(this IQueryable<T> entity,
    string param, Expression<Func<T, string>> selector)
{
    var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(
        Expression.GreaterThan(
            Expression.Call(
                typeof(SqlFunctions), "PatIndex", null,
                Expression.Constant(param, typeof(string)),
                selector.Body),
            Expression.Constant(0)),
        selector.Parameters);
    return entity.Where(lambda);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I guess I have to change `selector(l)` in some way? Because this snippet does not compile.

Comment: @Johan hmmm.... Yeah, that's a pain - didn't spit you were invoking it. To fix that you'll need to rebuild the expression tree with an expression-visitor. I'm on mobile - not ideal for giving an example of that. Not a trivial thing to do

Comment: Oh ok. I had no idea this was so hard to fix... :/

Comment: @Johan try the edit - it was a bit easier than I feared - didn't need a bull expression-visitor rebuild

Comment: Thanks a lot Marc, it seems to be working with a minor adjustment: `Expression.Constant(0)` to `Expression.Constant(0, typeof(int?))`. If I want to use this on more than one property, should i pass a dictinoary instead, and iterate over it? Otherwise I could just chain this method serveral times I suppose.

Comment: @Johan re the dictionary - hard to tell from your description; but whatever works

Comment: @MarcGravell - I have a generic repository pattern, which works during an intergration test, but fails in a unit test.  I originally had Expression<Func<TEntiy, bool>> filter = x => SqlFunctions.PatIndex(searchphrase, x.SearchString) > 0;  The filter then is add to the query so the simplified query is something like this: query.Where(filter).ToList().  This works perfect if I run the Web API and make a GET call to the endpoint.  That said, it breaks when I attempt to unit test this controller.  After it returned the error, I modified the code to match yours.  Still doesn't work.  Thoughts?