# This function can only be invoked from Linq to Entities in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

Why does the bottom linq to entity work but the top query that's commented out doesn't work?

```
var yogaProfile = dbContext.YogaProfiles.Where(i => i.ApplicationUserId == userId).First();
var yogaSpace = yogaProfile.YogaSpaces.Where(j => j.YogaSpaceId == yogaSpaceId).First();

if (yogaSpace == null)
 throw new Exception("You Don't Have A Yoga Space With This ID!");

var todayPlus30 = DateTime.Now.AddDays(30);
var yesterday = DateTime.Now.Date.AddDays(-1);

// Does not work!!
//var yogaEvents = yogaSpace.YogaSpaceEvents.Where(k => 
//    DbFunctions.TruncateTime(k.EventDateTime) > DbFunctions.TruncateTime(yesterday) && 
//    DbFunctions.TruncateTime(k.EventDateTime) < DbFunctions.TruncateTime(todayPlus30)).ToList();


var yogaEvents = yogaSpace.YogaSpaceEvents.Where(k =>
 k.EventDateTime.Date > yesterday &&
 k.EventDateTime.Date < todayPlus30);
```

Comment: Not showing us what DbFunctions.TruncateTime(...) does makes this hard to answer, since its obviously the only difference. Something in TruncateTime is using methods that are not supported for DB side methods.

Comment: `DbFunctions.etc (..` is not a Linq function, so it won't work

Answer (score 4):

Issue is that you are not using `DbFunctions` in correct context. These can be used in Linq-To-Entities but you have already fetched `yogaSpace` object using entity framework.

Now you are trying to get data from another IEnumerable  type data 
`YogaSpaceEvents` So it will not work with `Linq-To-Object` context.

In this case you can use standard date operation to overcome from issue..

See references:
[Linq Exception: Function can only be invoked from linq to entities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36216647/linq-exception-function-can-only-be-invoked-from-linq-to-entities)
[linq exception : This function can only be invoked from LINQ to Entities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18166183/linq-exception-this-function-can-only-be-invoked-from-linq-to-entities)
[EF extension method: "This function can only be invoked from LINQ to Entities."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17123341/ef-extension-method-this-function-can-only-be-invoked-from-linq-to-entities)